# Best way to adhere to DRY in Python with optional For clause

Tags: python, data-structures, iteration

I have a method that involves a very long if/elif block to convert attributes of a supplied object. I want to avoid having to use two methods. If the method can take either an iterable list or a single object that is not iterable, how can I make the if/elif block still execute if the object is not iterable?

Right now my code essentially looks like this:

```
def convert_orders(orders, orderid=None):
    """Converts certain fields of an order object to readable and/or indexable values"""

    status = None
    color = None
    order = None
    converted = []

    if not orders:
        order = session.query(Order).filter(Order.orderid == orderid)

    for order in orders:
        # convert order status to a string and give it a color for the tables
        if order.status == 0:
            status = 'In Progress'
            color = QColor(150, 255, 250)
        elif order.status == 1:
            status = 'Ready'
            color = QColor(60, 255, 75)

# elif continues below for another 70+ lines, converting other attributes.
```

If `orders` is provided as a list, but this method can also take `orderid` (an integer) how can I use only one elif block to convert either type, depending on which is provided? The method is invoked with either one type or the other but never both.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is just require `orders` to be iterable. What's wrong with a singleton list `convert_orders([my_one_order])` instead of `convert_orders(my_one_order)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if not orders:
    ...
    orders = (order,)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'status'`